# Membership user in ASP.NET‎ MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have been working on ASP.Net MVC3. I created view and controller. Also, I have a model to create account.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ----> if (model.UserName == "Guven" && model.Password == "12345")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

I want to make from the database to control that the line marked on the above code.My question is:How can I do that controller?

Comment: What does the builtin MembershipProvider and default AccountController not do that you require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `MembershipProvider` it has the [`ValidateUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validateuser.aspx) Method.

you'll need to change your marked line to:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
```

If your not using `MembershipProvider` yet, you'll might want to [implement it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx).

> There are two primary reasons for creating a custom membership
>   provider.
>
> - You need to store membership information in a data source that is not
>     supported by the membership providers included with the .NET
>     Framework, such as a FoxPro database, an Oracle database, or other
>     data sources.
> - You need to manage membership information using a database schema that
>     is different from the database schema used by the providers that ship
>     with the .NET Framework. A common example of this would be membership
>     data that already exists in a SQL Server database for a company or Web
>     site.

Have a look at: [Sample Membership Provider Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx)

Comment: First of all ,thanks for your interesting.As you said,How can I modify my controller code?Also,I have to pull from database user information.